# Saving data from custom form to db

Tags: php, forms, drupal

i have been trying to create a very simple form for a drupal site, the form displays all fields correctly. when trying to save the information to the database however i get an error.

i get: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) on line 286

i have been looking at severel guides on how to save data in drupal, and all agree that i should be using db_insert instead of a db_query with an insert statement, but for the life of me, i can't understand why i get this error. i have been looking at several examples including;

https://www.drupal.org/node/1164398

can anyone tell me why it isnt saving? and im getting the error?

```
function drupalform_form1_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $values = array(
    // CONTACT INFO

    'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],
    'phone' => $form_state['values']['phone'],

    // PARTICIPANT 1 VALUES
    'p1name' => $form_state['values']['p1name'],
    'p1nationality' => $form_state['values']['p1nationality'],
    'p1University' => $form_state['values']['p1University'],   
    'p1year' => $form_state['values']['p1year'],  

    // PARTICIPANT 2 VALUES
    'p2name' => $form_state['values']['p2name'],
    'p2nationality' => $form_state['values']['p2nationality'],
    'p2University' => $form_state['values']['p2University'],   
    'p2year' => $form_state['values']['p2year'], 

    // PARTICIPANT 3 VALUES
    'p3name' => $form_state['values']['p3name'],
    'p3nationality' => $form_state['values']['p3nationality'],
    'p3University' => $form_state['values']['p3University'],   
    'p3year' => $form_state['values']['p3year'],

    // PARTICIPANT 4 VALUES
    'p4name' => $form_state['values']['p4name'],
    'p4nationality' => $form_state['values']['p4nationality'],
    'p4University' => $form_state['values']['p24niversity'],   
    'p4year' => $form_state['values']['p4year']  
  );

  $insert = db_insert('bte_handin')->fields(array(

      // INSERTING CONTACT INFO

      'email' => $values['email'],
      'phone' => $values['phone'],

      // INSERTING PARTICIPANT 1
      'p1name' => $values['p1name'],
      'p1nationality' => $values['p1nationality'],
      'p1University' => $values['p1University'],
      'p1year' => $values['p1year'],

      // INSERTING PARTICIPANT 2
      'p2name' => $values['p2name'],
      'p2nationality' => $values['p2nationality'],
      'p2University' => $values['p2University'],
      'p2year' => $values['p2year'],

      // INSERTING PARTICIPANT 3
      'p3name' => $values['p3name'],
      'p3nationality' => $values['p3nationality'],
      'p3University' => $values['p3University'],
      'p3year' => $values['p3year'],

      //INSERTING PARTICIPANT 4
      'p4name' => $values['p4name'],
      'p4nationality' => $values['p4nationality'],
      'p4University' => $values['p4University'],
      'p4year' => $values['p4year'],

    ))->execute(); This is where the error is occuring


   drupal_set_message("Your answer has ben saved");
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Is this the *entire* code?

Comment: No i excluded the form itself.